# Fetch index information in PostgreSQL 8.4

Tags: php, postgresql, postgresql-8.4

I need to fetch the following information about indices on a specific table:

- index name
- columns that are indexed
- unique or not?

How can I do that in PostgreSQL 8.4?

**NOTE**: I have to be able to call this stuff with PHP. Just saying...

**EDIT**: I first had this query, but it only works starting with PostgreSQL 9.0:

```
SELECT t.relname AS table_name,
relname AS index_name,
a.attname AS column_name,
ix.indisunique
FROM pg_class t,
pg_class i,
pg_index ix,
pg_attribute a,
pg_constraint c
WHERE t.oid = ix.indrelid
  AND i.oid = ix.indexrelid
  AND a.attrelid = t.oid
  AND i.oid = c.conindid
  AND a.attnum = ANY(ix.indkey)
  AND c.contype != 'p'
  AND t.relkind = 'r'
  AND t.relname = 'tablename'
ORDER BY t.relname, i.relname
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply use [pg_indexes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/view-pg-indexes.html) which will include  the full CREATE TABLE statement (and therefor the information about the columns and the uniqueness).

Alternatively, the following should work:

```
select t.relname as table_name,
       ix.relname as index_name,
       array_to_string(array_agg(col.attname), ',') as index_columns,
       i.indisunique
from pg_index i
  join pg_class ix on ix.oid = i.indexrelid
  join pg_class t on t.oid = i.indrelid
  join (select ic.indexrelid, 
               unnest(ic.indkey) as colnum
        from pg_index ic) icols on icols.indexrelid = i.indexrelid
  join pg_attribute col on col.attrelid = t.oid and col.attnum = icols.colnum
where t.relname = 'tablename'
group by t.relname, ix.relname, i.indisunique
order by t.relname,
         ix.relname
```

It doesn't return the columns in the correct order though. But I didn't have time to dig deeper into that.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try that and report back.

Comment: It seems to work quite well (I had to add a WHERE clause for only getting indices on a specific table - maybe you could add that to your answer). I will try to find a solution for the column order thing.

Comment: Would you mind telling me why you were worried about the order, though? When could this happen / be a problem?

Comment: @Franz: the order of columns in an index is important. So any statement showing that should get that correct. At least one index on my computer was shown with the wrong order. I guess that is because unnest() does not guarantee a certain order of elements.

Comment: Oh, any good ideas on how to fix that? Just pointing me in the right direction might be enough... ;) Can PHP deal with arrays as return values?

Comment: @Franz: Currently I don't have an idea. I tried to somehow get the array index in the inner derived table (the one with the unnest) but to no avail. I don't know PHP, sorry